# VS Code and Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

just reinstalled VS code on my new Mac, and everytime I start it it asks me to install python. Python is referenced in the .zshrc to my brew install, it is also correctly referenced in VS Code, and I have no issues working in python it just throws the error when I open a Python file.

[Screen shot of VS Code, bar and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G01Wr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended that after installing python outside VS Code, open the python environment variable and check whether it contains the path of python you need to use:

[image]

Then we can enter "python" in the system terminal outside VS Code to check if it is available:

[image]

Also, if it still doesn't work, please try to reinstall [python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and the python extension in VS Code and reload VS Code.

Reference: [Preparation for using python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_prerequisites).

Comment: Thanks I think that worked, the error has dissapeared the last time I opened.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the python.pythonpath setting in VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter